# Identifying Unique Rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, reporting

I have an excel spreadsheet that contains over 20,000 rows and between 20/30 columns.

What is the easiest way to identify the rows that are unique - i.e a process that iterates through the rows and genrates a sum of the number of unique rows within the datasheet?

I would like this to be self-contained within a worksheet - i.e. a macro, but am open to other suggestions should the above approach be deemed inappropriate for whatever reason.

Comment: My free [Duplicate Master addin](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2123.html) will do this and more.

Answer (score 0):

concatenate all fields in a row for all rows and count the occurences, just with worksheet functions. Otherwise do this via a vba script,create a loop from the next to current row till the last row to find a duplicate and exit it when a duplicate is found.

Post your script when you get stuck again.

Comment: I'd start in the same way, i.e., concatenating all fields. Would then sort on the concatenated field, flag the dups with a simple if in a new column (e.g., if a3 = a2 then 1 else 0). Then, can count the dups, or the non-dups as number of rows of data minus dups, & sort again to flush dups to bottom of list.